# Issue getting a file with Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi I do not know what is happening but I want to get a file from the storage folder and it says that it does not existe but it exists I mean I go to the folder and it is there..

I retrieve the file like this:

```
$path = storage_path('app/public/' . $settlement->support);
$settlement_file = Storage::disk('local')->get($path);
```

And I get this error:

```
  message: "File not found at path: 
  home/jysparki/newjis.jisparking.com/storage/app/public/06152617_8-2025.pdf"
```

and If I go to the folder it exists so I wonder what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: please add a pic of folder structure with file itself in that directory, I've seen many time issues like this might end up, typo issues or etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `config/filesystems.php` file and find `disks` array, you may notice that `root` under the `local` disk key is set to `storage_path('app')`. Well it's up to what the value may be in your case you're free to change it, but what does this mean is whenever you call `Storage::disk('local')` method it will try to find files relative to `storage_path('app')`, so there is no need to specify full path. Try this instead

```php
$settlement_file = Storage::disk('local')->get('/public/' . $settlement->support);
```

or

```php
$settlement_file = Storage::disk('public')->get($settlement->support);
```

as Laravel by default has `public` disk which pointed into `/app/public` storage directory